# SVG will not display in browser

Tags: svg

I am trying to display a simple bar in the browser using svg but for some reason it is not displaying. Here is the code I am using. It does not display the bar.

```
  <h3>SVG Bar</h3>
  <svg>
  <rect with="50" height="200" style="fill: blue"/>
  </svg>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: typo: just write width instead of with ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've written your `width` attribute as "with".

But even correcting the typo, you can make a few more improvements:

```css
svg {
border: 1px solid black;
width: 20vw;
height: 20vw;
}
```

```html
<h3>SVG Bar</h3>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
<rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="500" style="fill: blue">
</svg>
```

Comment: namespaces are not required for inline svg, version is also pointless.

Comment: Thanks for that pointer, @RobertLongson - I don't tend to include my own SVGs inline, so I genuinely wasn't sure.